# How to run cucumber scenario with and without javascript avoiding code duplication

Tags: ruby, testing, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I was wondering if there is any way to run cucumber scenario with and without javascript without duplicating code.

I develop website that utilizes html5 navigation. However it should work find if browser doesn't support html5 features.

I would like to write cucumber test that would test navigation.
I know I can test basic html navigation with simple cucumber scenario. And I can test html5 navigation with same scenario but with @javascript tag.

I would really love to avoid this code duplication.
I was experimenting with around hooks, hoping that I could simple call block, then call same block with

```
Capybara.using_driver(Capybara.javascript_driver) { block.call }
```

However this doesn't work.

Anyone have any idea how to implement this?

P.S.
I'm quite new to Ruby, and just started working with cucumber.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need two different scenarios. I'd use the [Background](https://www.relishapp.com/cucumber/cucumber/docs/background) feature to avoid step definitions but it's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the solution by Jon M of using the environment variable, you need to set the current_driver before each scenario runs (which seems better than changing the default_driver).

```
Before do
  if ENV['USE_JS_DRIVER']
    Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver
  end
end
```

And then running

```
cucumber .
USE_JS_DRIVER=1 cucumber .
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create separate features to deal with both types of browser, then one solution is to use an environment variable to tell cucumber which type of browser driver to use, and invoke cucumber twice.

You'd need to query the environment variable to set the correct driver, probably in `env.rb`:

```
if ENV['USE_JS_DRIVER']
    Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver
end
```

And then you could run either/both of:

```
cucumber .
USE_JS_DRIVER=1 cucumber .
```

You'd have to find some useful way of merging the results from both cucumber runs, but depending on your needs this could be a simpler solution than duplicating your scenarios.

Comment: I think I rather write preprocessor, that can extract steps that need be executed with and without @javascript. That way coverage would be consistent

Comment: Just been banging my head against a table for the last few hours using this method. Only the first Scenario gets run using the javascript_driver (if you don't have @javascript tags) as the current_driver gets reset back to the default_driver before the next scenario runs. If you want all scenarios to run with the javascript_driver then you need to set the default_driver

Capybara.default_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver